# Searching through the Root Container doesn't find all text fields?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using a function to update my text fields on the stage:

```
private function updateFields(rootContainer:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    for(var i=0; i < rootContainer.numChildren; i++) {
        var item:* = rootContainer.getChildAt(i);
        try {
            updateFields(item);
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace(e.toString());
        }
        if (item.toString() == '[object TextField]') {
            trace(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

It finds half of the text fields placed on stage. Why is this? Drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
private function updateFields(rootContainer:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    for (var i:uint = 0, n:uint = rootContainer.numChildren; i < n; ++i) {
        var item:DisplayObject = rootContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (item is DisplayObjectContainer) {
            updateFields(DisplayObjectContainer(item));
        } else if (item is TextField) {
            trace(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed `DisplayObjectContainer` casting

Comment: I get "1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer."

Are your underlying implementation different?

Comment: Fixed `DisplayObjectContainer` casting.

Comment: A further question, you solved my life so far. The reference to item is static so i can't seem to change the value of the text field when doing: item.text = "text".

How do i find the reference to the object.

Comment: What does "The reference to item is static" mean?  `item` will reference a different object on each iteration of the loop.  And if `item` holds a dynamic TextField, you should be able to change the text by using `item.text`.

Comment: By doing "item.text  = "hej";"

I get 1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.